# Passing class with generic arguments to annotation

Tags: java, generics, types

I would like to know why this assignment is not accepted by Java compiler:

```
Class<? extends List<?>> blbost = ArrayList.class;
```

Please note  that I'm not interested in solution such as `Class<? extends List<?>> blobst = (Class<? extends List<?>>)ArrayList.class;`, I wonder what is the reason why it can be used.

---

The original motivation is using generics in an annotation:

```
@SomeAnnotation(SomeFunction.class) // Syntax error here!
private static class SomeClass  {
}

private @interface SomeAnnotation {
    Class<? extends Function<?, ?>> value();
}
private static class SomeFunction<T> implements Function<T, String> {
    @Override
    public String apply(T t) {
        return t.toString();
    }
}
```

I cannot use the cast in annotation because the value must be constant.

Why can't I pass `SomeFunction` as an argument to `SomeAnnotation` and what can I do about it?

Comment: I think this should help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html. `Class<ArrayList>` is not a subclass of `Class<List<?>>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why `ArrayList` is not a subtype of `List<?>` is because generics in Java are `invariant`, meaning that for any two distinct types `Type1` and `Type2`, `List<Type1>` is neither a sub- nor a supertype of `List<Type2>`.

This also extends to raw types and parameterized types, meaning that a raw type like `ArrayList` can never be sub- nor super type of a parameterized type like `List<Type1>` and, perhaps more intuitively, a parameterized type like `ArrayList<Type1>` can never be a subtype of a raw type like `List`, even though `ArrayList` is a subtype of `List`.

Removing the wildcard from the inner type will allow you to pass the raw type class into the annotation:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Example {
    @SomeAnnotation(SomeFunction.class)
    private static class SomeClass {

    }

    private @interface SomeAnnotation {
        Class<? extends Function> value();
    }

    private static class SomeFunction<T> implements Function<T, String> {
        @Override
        public String apply(T t) {
            return t.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Not also that it is impossible to obtain a class literal from a parameterized type like `List<String>`. For any type `Type`, `List<Type>.class` will be a syntax error, so using the raw type here is permissible, even though generally you shouldn't use raw types.

Answer (score 6):

First, the short answer is that `Class<ArrayList>` is not a subtype of `Class<? extends List<?>>`. There is actually a relationship like in the following diagram:

```
                      Class
                        |
                     Class<?>
                        |
              Class<? extends List>
                  /           \
Class<? extends List<?>>    Class<? extends ArrayList>
         |                             |
   Class<List<?>>              Class<ArrayList>
```

In other words, `Class<ArrayList>` and `Class<? extends List<?>>` share a common supertype.

This is mostly covered in sections [4.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2) and [4.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) of the specification.

An assignment such as `Class<? extends List<?>> cls = ArrayList.class` would compile if `Class<? extends List<?>>` was a supertype of `Class<ArrayList>`, so we need to find out what the supertypes of `Class<ArrayList>` are:

> Given a generic type declaration `C<F1,...,Fn>` (*n* > 0), the direct supertypes of the parameterized type `C<T1,...,Tn>`, where `Ti` (1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*) is a type, are all of the following:
>
> 1. `D<U1 θ,...,Uk θ>`, where `D<U1,...,Uk>` is a generic type which is a direct supertype of the generic type `C<T1,...,Tn>` and `θ` is the substitution `[F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn]`.
> 2. `C<S1,...,Sn>`, where `Si` contains `Ti` (1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*).
> 3. The type `Object`, if `C<F1,...,Fn>` is a generic interface type with no direct superinterfaces.
> 4. The raw type `C`.

Rule 1 is basically just saying that if you have a type e.g. `ArrayList<String>` then it has supertypes `List<String>`, `Iterable<String>`, etc., where the type argument is merely substituted in to the superclass or superinterface. `Class` has no relevant supertypes of this kind, because for this particular example we don't care about its superclasses or superinterfaces.

Rule 2 is the only one that we're actually interested in here, and the JLS directs us to 4.5.1 for an explanation of when a type argument contains another type argument:

> A type argument `T1` is said to *contain* another type argument `T2`, written `T2 <= T1`, if the set of types denoted by `T2` is provably a subset of the set of types denoted by `T1` under the reflexive and transitive closure of the following rules (where `<:` denotes subtyping):
>
> - `? extends T <= ? extends S` if `T <: S`
> - [...]
> - `T <= ? extends T`
> - [...]

Using those two rules and the transitive property we can deduce a rule that a type argument `? extends S` contains a type argument `T` if `S` is a supertype of `T`.

Using this rule, we can now frame the original problem as follows:

1. `Class<? extends List<?>>` is a supertype of `Class<ArrayList>` if `? extends List<?>` contains `ArrayList`.
2. `? extends List<?>` contains `ArrayList` if `List<?>` is a supertype of `ArrayList`.

So what are the supertypes of the raw type `ArrayList`? We can refer back to 4.10.2:

> Given a generic type declaration `C<F1,...,Fn>` (*n* > 0), the direct supertypes of the raw type `C` are all of the following:
>
> 1. The direct superclass of the raw type `C`.
> 2. The direct superinterfaces of the raw type `C`.
> 3. The type `Object`, if `C<F1,...,Fn>` is a generic interface type with no direct superinterfaces.

(Rule 3 is irrelevant to the example we're thinking about here.)

Also, we need a quick jump to [4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> The superclasses (respectively, superinterfaces) of a raw type are the erasures of the superclasses (superinterfaces) of any of the parameterizations of the generic type.

In other words, the supertypes of `ArrayList` are all of the raw types `AbstractList`, `List`, `Iterable`, etc.

From all of this, we can finally conclude that `Class<ArrayList>` is not a subtype of `Class<? extends List<?>>`, and this is why the assignment in the question doesn't compile.

---

As far as solutions that don't involve casting, Marv has shown one of them, which is to change `Class<? extends Function<?, ?>>` to `Class<? extends Function>`.

Another would be to never use e.g. a `SomeFunction.class`, which has the raw type argument `Class<SomeFunction>`. Instead, you'd always extend `SomeFunction` with concrete type arguments. For example, if you want a `SomeFunction<Double>`, you'd create an explicit subclass:

```
class DoubleFunction extends SomeFunction<Double> {}
```

And then you'd be able to use `DoubleFunction.class`.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't hoping for such comprehensive answer! I accepted Marv's answer because he was first and we used his solution, but your answer is great. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I'm glad to help.